# perl to open file with yesterday's date in localtime()

Tags: perl

i need to open files with todays date and yesterdays date i can open todays file ok but am don't know how to open yesterdays, i am using localtime because my perl verson is 5.8.8.
 so the other time/date modules are not available
this is what i have so far

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

@months = qw( Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec );
@days = qw(Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun);

($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday,$isdst) = localtime(); 
$year = $year+1900;

print "c:\\DBR_$year\\$months[$mon]\\Failures_output\\$mday$months[$mon]report.csv"
    || die "can't open output file for reading: $!";
```

this prints

```
c:\DBR_2014\May\Failures_output\5Mayreport.csv
```

now how do i open same files with yesterdays date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `localtime`/`mktime` roundtrip will give you the epoch number for midnight at the start of yesterday (i.e. the time where `mday` is 1 less than now)

```
use POSIX 'mktime';

my @now = localtime();
my $yesterday = mktime 0, 0, 0, $now[3]-1, $now[4], $now[5];
```

You can then put this into `strftime` to give you the time string; you don't need to have an array of months like that

```
use POSIX 'strftime';

my $path = strftime("c:\\DBR_%Y\\%b\\Failures_output\\%d%breport.csv", localtime($yesterday));
```

(You don't have to worry about the case where `mday` is already 1 because `mktime` will handle that properly).

Comment: avoid weird dst issues some places by passing 12 as the hour to mktime

Answer (score 0):

`localtime` can take an epoch seconds argument, so do get yesterday's date, just call

```
@yesterday = localtime( time - 86400 );   # 86400 = 24 * 60 * 60
```

Comment: This won't quite work during the day of the year that DST reverts back to standard time. The previous day was therefore only 23 hours long; if you make this call during the first hour of the day just afterwards, you'll skip right over yesterday and hit the day before. Hence why the `localtime`/`mktime` roundtrip with mday - 1.